# What was the cause of the second explosion in SpaceX's pad "Fast Fire"?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, failure, launchpad, rocket-explosion

This is well after the first and second stage were gone, so I suspect it was something about the pad itself that resulted in the second explosion event. Any ideas?

Comment: No info yet, even SpaceX has said that doesn't know for the moment. You will know after some months from internet websites, it won't be a secret info and very difficult to find, for sure a lot websites will write for this.

Comment: I haven't seen this particular event acknowledged at all, so...

Comment: I believe someone mentioned on /r/SpaceX that it was an RP-1 tank on the pad; don't have sources, though.

Comment: @DylanSp I suspected as much as well, but I haven't seen it mentioned at all really, except for briefly in this video. I don't know what else could have caused this to happen, however, it's not like they keep explosive things near a launch pad that don't need to be there!

Comment: Look here: https://m.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/5b2muh/peter_b_de_selding_spacex_statement_late_nov_3/     This is interesting they have found it, soon will announce what was the cause.

Comment: OMG, first I've thought it was a recent event... :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A firefighter on the scene reported that a number of train rail cars, and ground support tanks were burned and blew up in the process.  Could be one of any of those.

Comment: I would suspect the latter, but what is meant by a "ground support tank"?

Comment: A place to hold fuel before it's pumped into the rocket.