# ULA's plan for LH2/LOX 2nd stage that can maintain propellant for an extended period of time?

Tags: liquid-fuel, cryogenics, ula

Business Insider's (long) article [SpaceX's biggest rival has a 'genius' plan to cut its rocket launch costs more than 70%](http://www.businessinsider.com/how-vulcan-rocket-works-united-launch-alliance-2018-2#since-bruno-took-the-helm-of-ula-in-2014-the-company-has-been-developing-its-more-powerful-and-partly-reusable-vulcan-rocket-system-thats-supposed-to-launch-for-the-first-time-in-mid-2020-2) contains the statements sourced from ULA's CEO Tory Bruno:

> Vulcan should lift 40 tons (nearly three school buses) into low-Earth orbit. That's less than SpaceX's Falcon Heavy, which can lift more than 70 tons — nearly five school buses — for one-fourth the price. But Bruno said there are big differences between the two systems that will make Vulcan competitive.
>
> The key difference is the rocket's upper stage. Falcon Heavy currently uses a rocket-grade RP-1 kerosene as fuel, but it can freeze in space after a few hours. Vulcan's upper stage will use cryogenic oxygen and hydrogen, which are more resilient to the punishing temperatures of space.

LH2 and LOX have about the same molar density, but the stoichiometry requires twice as many moles of LH2. If the tanks are end-to-end, it would mean the LH2 tank intercepts close to twice as much geometrical exposure to the environment as the LOX tank. However, the [Enthalpy of vaporization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization) of LH2 on a *molar basis* is only one quarter that of LOX (see [LH2](https://technifab.com/cryogenic-resource-library/cryogenic-fluids/liquid-hydrogen/) and [LOX](https://technifab.com/cryogenic-resource-library/cryogenic-fluids/liquid-oxygen/)).

Further, at 1 atmosphere for example, LH2 boils at around 20K while LOX boils at around 90K. That means without active refrigeration, the heat loading would have to be of the order of $(4.5)^4$ times lower if LH2 was used (assuming passive radiation for cooling), which would be a real challenge in sunlight.

There are <s>two</s> three parts to this question. If I have to split them I will but it's possible an answer can address both at the same time.

1. Is ULA likely to consider putting the 2nd stage LH2 tank *inside* the LOX tank (or at least be surrounded by it coaxially)?
2. Unless the second stage is going to Jupiter or beyond, isn't the heating from Sunlight boiling the LH2 a more challenging problem than "freezing" of the RP-1? (See [Does the NK-33 engine require subcooled kerosene so cold that it turns to wax?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14456/12102) for some density vs temperature plots.)
3. In order to keep the LH2 cold for months, would the 2nd stage end up looking a little bit like the the JWST with those large metallized polymer layers deployed to block the Sun?

---

### Temperature of a [Spherical Cow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow) in Space:

[image]

Spherical cow as illustrated by a 1996 meeting of the American Astronomical Association, in reference to astronomy modeling. From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SphericalCow2.gif): "The image was created by Ingrid Kallick for the program cover of the 1996 annual meeting of the American Astronomical Association. An earlier version was created for the National Center for Supercomputing Applications. The artist gave permission for use to the University of Wisconsin Department of Astronomy. The STScI subsequently used the image. http://www.ikallick.com"

[Equilibrium temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_equilibrium_temperature) happens when *average power in* equals *average power out*, or $\bar{P}_{in} - \bar{P}_{out}$. Averaging should be done over short term variations in attitude relative to the Sun and take into account eclipses for most orbits near the Earth, Moon, or another planet.

$$\bar{P}_{in} = I_{Sun} (1-a) \ \pi R^2$$

$$\bar{P}_{out} = \sigma \epsilon T^4 \ 4 \pi R^2 $$

where $a_{vis}$ is the visible light albedo, $e_{ir}$ is the infrared emissivity (both should really be weighted averages over the appropriate wavelength ranges; [@Tristan's](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18100/why-are-rtgs-different-colors#comment47061_18103) and [@Puffin's](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21524/what-are-these-very-large-square-panels-on-inmarsat-5s#comment60250_21547) comments explain this better than their associated answers do), $\sigma$ is the [Stefan–Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) (about 5.67E-08 W m^-2 K^-4), and I is the intensity of sunlight, and for 1AU is the [solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant) and about 1360 W/m^2. Solving for the average equilibrium temperature of said cow gives:

$$T \sim \left( \frac{(1-a_{vis})}{e_{ir}} \frac{I_{Sun}}{4 \sigma} \right)^{1/4}$$

For an average *visible-light* albedo of 0.95, and an average *infrared* emissivity of 0.95. this turns out to be about 130 Kelvin at 1 AU, and about 110 Kelvin near Mars, and because of the fourth-root, this varies only slowly with any of the parameters. It seems that space is much more LOX-friendly than LH2-friendly, and only moderate Sun-shielding measures would be necessary to get the LOX down below boiling at 1 atmosphere pressure, like simply having the 2nd stage face the Sun end-on, because cows are not actually spherical.

**But what about the RP-1?**

If the albedo of a hypothetical "LOX compartment" were 0.1 instead of 0.95 (if it were 18 times more absorbing of sunlight), the temperature would rise by the fourth root of 18, or about a factor of two (see my thoughtful (and *unnecessarily* down-voted) tutorial on the use of [power laws in physics](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25331/12102)). That would put the RP-1 up near a balmy 273 K or 0C, "[sub-cooled](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14456/12102)" and ready to go! This can be confirmed by the plot of equilibrium temperature of temperature for a spherical blackbody around each of the planets (ignoring eclipses and planetary albedo) found in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/7913/12102).

Comment: If the LH2 tank is in the LOX tank, there should be only a small deposit of solid oxygen. Too much SOX means loosing oxygen for the burn as well as boiled off hydrogen by letting oxygen freeze

Comment: It's a good point, but I think if there are no mechanical problems with SOX, if it doesn't cause thinks to break or blow up (I mean cause them to erupt into a "[fast fire anomaly](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18141/12102)" as Musk calls it), then an electric heater can always restore it to LOX, using power from solar panels, or if it's hibernating in deep space, perhaps even a liquid heat exchange from an RTG directly (which sounds messy and complicated).

Comment: 1 would cause too many problems prelaunch and be heavy 2 -yes 3 - maybe

Comment: @OrganicMarble it's the 80:20 rule; a question that takes more than 80 minutes to think about, write, and "debug" takes less than 20 words to answer ;-)

Comment: Well comment on anyway :) Not a real answer.  That's an interesting article but it's not clear if ACES is planned to remain fueled after its mission or not. You could read it as if ACES will hang around in orbit awaiting refueling.

Comment: @OrganicMarble the blurb I'm quoting touts LH2 as better than RP-1 because of its "resilien(ce) to the punishing temperatures of space" for times longer than "a few hours".

Comment: Comparing the boiling point of methane at 111.66 K and its freezing point of 90.7 K with the boiling point of oxygen at 90.188 K, there is unfortunately no temperature range in which both methane and oxygen will be liquid. But they are very close. May be a small part of hydrogen will move the freezing point of a mixture CH4 with H2 into the right direction.

Comment: Kutter and Zegler of ULA propose to use hydrogen boil off for station keeping. Ordinary station keeping creates heat but their station keeping scheme is a form of evaporative cooling. For low earth orbit they propose conical MLI (Multi Layer Insulation) shades whose axis points north and south. K & Z and ULA have some online pdfs that can easily be found by Googling.

Comment: @HopDavid I'm sure it's possible. 0.5 grams of LOX/second would provide roughly 100W of cooling and result in only 40 kg/day loss. But my question is centered around why the article suggests that using LH2 is *somehow superior* to using RP-1; that it somehow solves a problem that RP-1 poses.

Comment: Well, you oughtn't expect Business Insider to be technically literate or coherent. That said, LH2 is hugely superior in specific impulse; it solves the problem that RP-1 has of needing a larger first stage to lift an equivalent payload/∆v worth of second stage.

Comment: A loss of 40 kg/day is 1000kg in 25 days. Is this acceptable for some month?

Comment: @RussellBorogove I've just added the two immediately preceding sentences, which attribute the argument to ULA's CEO Tory Bruno. However, yes they could be misunderstanding what they were told. Higher Isp propellants in the second stage would indeed allow for more payload mass for a given first stage design. That's similar to what you said, but phrased differently, since the use RP-1 in the second stage does not seem to posing any actual problem for SpaceX's phenomenal growth and launching of actual-, as opposed to  ULA's mid 2020's future-rockets.

Comment: Sure it's causing problems for SpaceX; their GTO and beyond payloads are poor compared to their LEO payloads because they're using RP-1. Everything in engineering is a tradeoff. ULA likes to portray SpaceX's tradeoffs as fatal flaws, like saying their reusability plan costs SpaceX 30% of payload, overlooking that a customer with a 4t satellite doesn't care whether SpaceX can send 8t or 11t to GTO and that SpaceX can fly expendable if need be. Meanwhile, ULA is telling us how great their rocket is going to be, one day, soon, sometime after they decide what engine ACES is going to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ACES stage](https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/exploration/evolving-to-a-depot-based-space-transportation-architecture.pdf) is designed for a lifetime of weeks, not years.

1. The tanks will be simply stacked on top of each other. There's no plan to place the LH tank inside the LOX tank.

[image: ACES stage with tanks in series]

> ACES design is optimized with long-duration cryogenic applications in mind. A number of passive-thermal management features are incorporated into the stage at the system level. The tank geometry design minimizes the exposed surface area. Warm equipment is isolated on a separate, thermally controlled shelf, and IVF systems provide a stable thermal environment regardless of vehicle orientation. This is critical for depot applications. Vapor- cooling paths, where vented hydrogen is used to intercept the remaining high-load heat paths, are integrated into the tank structure.

2. and 3: the plan is to use the boiloff to power an internal combustion engine. The [Integrated Vehicle Fluids](https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/extended-duration/integrated-vehicle-propulsion-and-power-system-2011.pdf) system replaces batteries, ullage thrusters, attitude thrusters and the tank pressurization system.

The long-term storage facility may be a [separate ULA development](http://sites.nationalacademies.org/cs/groups/depssite/documents/webpage/deps_061677.pdf) called Long Duration CPS where they're looking at dewar storage.

[image]

> Earth Departure Stage
>    – Mars or NEO return stage
>    – Lunar lander
>    – Propellant depot
>    - Return stage mission duration
>
> Multi year mission with very low boil-off
>      – 1 year: 0.027%/day
>    – 2 year: 0.014%/day
>    – 3 year: 0.009%/day
>    – 4 year: 0.007%/day
>
> On orbit fueling allows:
>    – Structure/insulation to not be driven by launch environment
>    – Reduced structural heat leak paths
>    – Very high mass fraction (>0.90)

Comment: I like this answer, but the last link doesn't take me anywhere relevant, just to a ULA picture gallery.

Comment: A fuel cell stack may be used instead of an internal combustion engine. A combustion engine might need a fuel rich mix to limit the temperature. The monocoque tank  walls and the common bulkhead require extra isolation in the area between LOX and LH2 to limit the heatflow from oxygen to hydrogen. The use of vapor cooling paths to intercept heat is a good idea.

Comment: IVF explicitly specifies an ICE because they use the exhaust products for thrust.

Comment: and I fixed the last link.

Comment: @Hobbes this is exactly what I needed, thank you! The internal combustion engine (ICE) and use of its energy bi-products, milli-G continuous vehicle settling, and use of H2/O2 for thrusters look like some of the important design elements. I'll take some more time to read through more carefully. Who would have thought that in the 21st century engineers would do a run-off between an in-line ["Straight-six"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight-six_engine)" cylinder engine and a [Wankel rotary engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wankel_engine) to take us to the stars! ;-)

Comment: A mass is not measured in millitesla. The metric symbol for a metric tonne is t, see [Wikipedia about tonne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonne). Instead of t Mg may be used. But mT means millitesla.

Comment: Americans talking about metric units find it necessary to specify they're talking about metric tons, and not one of the two imperial variants of 'ton'. From the context it's obvious they're not talking about magnetic fields.

Comment: Hey, but at SpaceX launch costs are measured in kiloTeslas. ;-)

Comment: @Hobbes: Or they can use the spelling "tonne", which is used _only_ for the metric version.