# What is the solar flux on Titan?

Tags: temperature, saturn, titan

I' trying to solve for the surface temperature Ts=((n+1)So(1-A)4)1/4, and thus So=L/4a2 but I cannot seem to find the value for solar flux or its luminosity.

Comment: Your equations seem a little messed up, and I don't trust a blind MathJax conversion. Are there some exponents in there that you left out?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I agree. It's probably something like one of these, but I don't know what the (n+1) is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_equilibrium_temperature#Calculation_of_semi-blackbody_temperature See also cow: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25671/12102

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [solar flux at 1 AU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant) (Earth's distance from the sun) is ~1361 W/m<sup>2</sup>. Flux falls off as the square of distance. [Saturn, on average -- and thus Titan, on average -- is about 9.58 AU from the sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn), so the falloff factor is 1 / 9.58<sup>2</sup> or 0.0109.

Titan should average about 1361 x 0.0109 = 14.8 W/m<sup>2</sup> when not shadowed by the gas giant.

When Saturn is at its furthest from the sun, 10.12 AU, the flux would be closer to 13.3 W/m<sup>2</sup>.